# fpdf pdf file size

Tags: pdf, fpdf, filesize

I am generating a one-page PDF with FPDF and the file size is massive (nearly 1.05 M). I only have 1 image and when I remove it, it takes out only about 22k, so although it is large, it is not that much of an impact on the file size. I am using some manually added fonts (via the FPDF directions). I have to set those fonts off and on throughout (for styling the pdf). Any thoughts on why this is so large? Do the custom fonts embed and add *that much* to the file size?

Comment: Have you done any research in the FPDF documentation to find your answer?

Comment: How many different fonts do you use?

Comment: @MECU i use 3 or 4 different fonts, and I am assuming this may be doing it.

Comment: @SnareChops I did do a search here and on the web to find it, so I do not think it warranted a vote down. I am new to fpdf and after not finding an answer I turned to actually ask.

Comment: @SnareChops after searching FPDF specifically outside of web search, both FAQ and forums do not seem to lend help

Comment: How large are the font files?

Comment: Try removing all font files. How big is it?

Comment: 1.05M isn't really THAT "massive"...

Comment: @MECU I agree that it is not that massive just seems a bit to much and if i can cut it down i would prefer that...

Comment: @PeeHaa I think that is the problem. The font files being called are PHP files however they call zip files that are huge. I think this is where it is at. The fonts being used are tahoma and verdana but they are not built into FPDF by default. Because those are on most client computers I could probably get away with not embedding it if i make sure they are named by the window's default name, right?

Comment: Not sure about that one.

Comment: all/@SnareChops, i did find a piece at the bottom of their addfont page that mentioned reducing file sizes of the font files so I definitely missed that. I am going to try that route so I can still embed the fonts and ensure my look. Any problem you guys can see with that?

Comment: You may want to check out whether you need all glyphs in the fonts.

Comment: Have you tried temporarily switching everything to Helvetica (which is standard and small) and then looking at the file size? How large is it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the fonts, they bloat the file big time.  I had a similar problem and the size went from 800k down to 60k when using only built in fonts (Helvetica).

Answer (score 1):

The huge size is purely due to the image file. I tried using an optimized version(reduced in file size for web use) of the image and the the PDF file size decreased considerably.

Also using images of the required dimensions will be more helpful. Initially my project was using images of dimension 4000x3000 for displaying in 50x50 space of the PDF file. I resized the images to a very less dimensions and BINGO!